# Does "yet" imply negativity in a question?

Tags: grammaticality

As I understand it, English's use of "yes" and "no" are distinct from "true" and "false".

> Does arXiV not host papers on biology?

Can be replied with either:

> Yes (arXiV does host papers on biology).
>
> No (arXiV does not host papers on biology).

But both answers seem uninformative when a question contains "yet":

> Have you yet to dine?

Would "yes" mean that one has already dined? Or that one has yet to dine?

Would "no" mean that one has not yet dined? Or that no, one has already dined?

Apart from the archaic sentence construction, what is missing/wrong about how I understand "yes"/"no" in English?

Comment: I think your premise is wrong. In my experience, on the rare occasions that someone tries to answer a question like "Does arXiV not host papers on biology?" with bare *yes*, the next question is almost invariably, "Yes, they do, or yes, they don't?" (And likewise for bare *no*.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Yet to" is indeed a kind of negative (note that it takes negative polarity items such as "any").

Your problem with Yes and No is a general problem with negative questions in English. Unlike French and German, we haven't a word that means "Yes, contrary to your suggestion or question", so "yes" and "no" are in general ambiguous in response to a negative question.

["Yet" on its own is quite different from "yet to": it is not a negator, but it is a negative polarity item].